# How to generate SonarQube report in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sonarqube, report

I am trying to implement sonarqube report for my project, My React native version is 0.60, I tried but can't achieve the desired result I wanted

Comment: Please explain in detail what you did and what you want to achieve so everyone can help you effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: These notes are for SonarQube (Community Edition - V8.0). The steps for setting up SonarQube may be different for other versions.
**Step 1: Download SonarQube**

1. Download the SonarQube (Community Edition - V8.0): https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/
2. Download the SonarQube Scanner (V4.2): https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/
3. Unzip the SonarQube
4. Unzip the SonarQube Scanner

**Step 2: Download and Install Java**
2.  Download and install Java SE Development Kit (v11.0.5): https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html

**Step 3: Setup Environment Variables**
3.  Add SonarQube Scanner path in Environment Variables.
a.  Right Click on This PC -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. Find "path" variable under the System Variables and add the path of folder where SonarQube is unzipped. In my case it was "C:\Users\  \Desktop\sonar-scanner-4.2-windows\bin”.
4.  Add Java path in Environment Variables.
.  Right Click on This PC -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. Find "path" Variable under the System Variables and Add the path of folder where JAVA (JDK) is installed. In my case it was "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5\bin".

**Step 4: Setup Properties**\n
Go to Sonar Scanner -> conf, and open sonar-scanner.properties file.
Replace the file content with the following content:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=influencer proj
# --- optional properties ---
# defaults to project key
sonar.projectName=ProjectName
# defaults to 'not provided'
sonar.projectVersion=1.0     
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=srcPath
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=./node_modules
sonar.exclusions=./.env
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=srcPath
sonar.host.url = http://localhost:9000
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=report/lcov.dat
sonar.javascript.node.maxspace=12096
#sonar.ws.timeout=1200   
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Go to project folder, create a file sonar-project.properties (The extension of file must be .properties)
Paste the following content in the file.
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
# sonar.projectKey=influencer proj

```
# --- optional properties ---

# defaults to project key
sonar.projectKey=porjectName
 # defaults to 'not provided'
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
sonar.language=js
sonar.sources=app
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=./node_modules
sonar.exclusions=./.env
sonar.sources=./src

sonar.host.url = http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=porjectKey
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=report/lcov.dat
sonar.javascript.node.maxspace=4096
sonar.ws.timeout=120
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=./
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

**Step 5: Run SonarQube and SonarScanner**
4.  Go to SonarQube folder -> bin -> windows-x86-64, and open StartSonar.bat. This should open console.
5.   Open browser, go to http://localhost:9000 - You will be able to see the results on this tab after running the scanner.
6.  Login with the following credentials:
Username: admin
Password: admin
6.  Open Visual Code Terminal, enter command "sonar-scanner.bat". This will scan the project folder.
7.  Refresh the browser. You should see the results in the browser.